# How to evaluate accuracy of Keras's Embeding Layer

Tags: python, keras, word-embedding

I'm trying to use Keras's Embedding Layer to build embeddings for my dataset. After I fit my dataset, I am able to access the trained embedding weights, and I dont really care about the model thats generated. I have a 2 part question:

1. Since the accuracy of the model is computed off the classification layer (Conv1D), does it also apply specifically to the embedding quality? For example, if I swap the Conv1D with LSTM which may yield better accuracy. Does it mean that the embedding quality has improved?
2. I have seen examples where the network setup is quite basic i.e. it's [Embedding - Flatten - Dense  ]. Does adding Conv1D/LSTM layers improve the embedding quality in any way?

Sample code:

```
    model = Sequential()
    embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=Vocab_size,output_dim=8,input_length=max_length)
    model.add(embedding_layer)
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='relu',
                             input_shape=(time_window_size, 1)))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])

    model.fit(padded_reviews,labels,epochs=100,verbose=0)
    print(embedding_layer.embeddings)
```

Thanks

Comment: In general, the embedding layers are just randomly initialized weights and are accessed via look-up tables. So, if you can make a better model that learns from the data better, whether it is a CNN or LSTM or otherwise, this means that, your embeddings will also be improved. This has to be the case because it is the embeddings that you are training and using to derive predictions. So as your architecture improves, so too does your weights; because the architecture improves them.

Comment: Help me out here, when a network undergoes the iterative training process/learning, the neuron weights in the CNN get adjusted at intervals. Are you saying the embedding weights too get continuously optimized throughout the process?

Comment: Theoretically speaking yes but many stuf could be happening , is embedding weights are the reason the network accuracy improved or mainly due to others layers and paramater, im not sure about that

Comment: Since i sense some vagueness, let me ask this, whats the best way of building word embedding? Is this the recommended approach?

Comment: Embeddings are standard. However, if you are interested in analyzing text, you should probably just make the jump towards transformers. They too use the same idea, except their embedding table has been trained for days on gigabytes of text. CNNs can be pretty good if you are limited to a CPU only option.

Comment: John can you pls point me to an example of building word embeddings using transformers on Keras?